# onselect datepicker event doesnt fire in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have this code in my ruby on rails project but i noticed that the datepicker onSelect event doest fire in a ruby on rails project for reasons unbeknown to me.

```
<label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Start Period</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <%= text_field_tag "start_period", nil,  
            class: "form-control ", 
            id: "activity-customer-start-period", 
            placeholder: ""
          %>

        </div>
        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">End Period</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <%= text_field_tag "end_period", nil,  
            class: "form-control", 
            id: "activity-customer-end-period", 
            placeholder: ""
          %>

        </div>
```

my js file

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#activity-customer-start-period').datepicker({
       format: 'dd M yyyy', 
       onSelect: function(selected) {
        alert(selected);
       }
    });

    $('#activity-customer-end-period').datepicker({ 
        format: 'dd M yyyy', 
        autoclose: true,
        minDate: $('#activity-customer-start-period').val(),
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            alert(selected);
          $("#activity-customer-start-period").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
        }
    });

});
```

Does anyone know why datepicker onselect event wont work in a rails project or even work properly. I included this jsfiddle file for assistance

http://jsfiddle.net/boyfunky/oqxxmrru/

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the datepicker() function itself firing?

Comment: Your code works fine when run in a Fiddle with jQuery UI. http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/160/ What is the exact issue you're facing? Are you sure jQuery UI is included in your project?

Comment: i want the end-date no to be lower than the start-date so the minDate for end-date shud be selected date of start-date. Butr if i select e.g 14/4/2015, end-date starts from 25/4/2015 dunno why it is jumping that far